# Can i build an iOS project using jenkins without provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I try to build my ios project using Jenkins without certificate and without provisioning profile

CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Error is clear, you have to sign your code, that means you need provision profile and certificate

Comment: Yes i understand the mean of the error but i believed that we can use other way to resolve this case, for example just build project without sign the ipa because it will be used only for the debug mode not for the distribution

Comment: Try to set Code Sign Identity in Build Settings to Don't Sign for 'Application'

Comment: i have done it but the same error persiste, my be i must create a provision profile :/